# New-AzureReservedIP : BadRequest : Cannot reserve the ip of deployment people-dns

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm new to Azure PowerShell, but now I'm running a command to have Azure reserve a static IP address:

```
New-AzureReservedIP -ReservedIPName "people-dns" -Location "West US" -ServiceName "people-dns"
```

And then I'm getting this error:

```
New-AzureReservedIP : BadRequest : Cannot reserve the ip of deployment people-dns.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureReservedIP -ReservedIPName "people-dns" -Location "West US" -ServiceNam ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureReservedIP], ComputeCloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.IaaS.NewAzureReservedIPCmdlet
```

I'm trying to figure out what's wrong - the error is not very descriptive …

**UPDATE 1:**
So, I tried to install the latest version of Azure command-line interface (but still not sure how to tell which version it is...)

**UPDATE 2:** 
I restarted the VM as suggested in order to let the Azure APIs to update,
My Azure Portal PUBLIC VIRTUAL IP (VIP) ADDRESS is 137.117.11.18 and my web site is still running so I don't understand why in the message it shows a different IP...

**I would love any suggestions on how to proceed or how to "update development/role"**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Name of the cloud service must be incorrect. Make sure -ServiceName is your cloud service name. It works for web/worker roles and Virtual Machines.

Also make sure you are running the latest version of powershell which is 0.9.5 atm. You can download it [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/). I had similar problems running 0.9.4.

-Location must also be in the same datacenter as your cloud service.

Comment: I want to make sure that the current dynamic IP does not change after that command - because if it does I will have to make some DNS changes... do you know if my static IP will be the same after these two commands? I followed this article: http://clemmblog.azurewebsites.net/convert-existing-dynamic-vip-reserved-ip-addresses-azure

Comment: updated the answer. yes, it works as it should. You can now convert the current dynamic VIP deployed in your VM to reserved IP. No changes to DNS will be needed nor downtimes. thanks for the tip, didn't know it was possible with the latest updates. Tested in my lab. Only worked with powershell 0.9.5. Check your module version with the cmdlet  (Get-Module Azure).version

Comment: I'm curious... how can I check which version is it? I have to say - this Azure PowerShell is not very intuitive...

Comment: i told you in the last comment. Use "(Get-Module Azure).version" at powershell

Comment: Oh, thanks for your help, I missed that... so I'm running on the latest version but still got the error below (image attached)  Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
0      9      5      -1

Comment: I'm going to try to shut down the VM as you suggested.

Comment: Hi Bruno, I restarted the VM, but still getting errors, I will appreciate if you can take a look at the new screen shot (UPDATE 2). Thanks!

Comment: Did you shutdown or just a restart? VM needs to be deallocated.

Comment: I thought restart is the same... so I will try it again next week, do you think I should do something to preserve the current public IP? maybe run Remove-AzureReservedIP before I shut down?

Comment: If you didn't reserve and you can't reserve it right now because of the version of your running cloud service you will likely loose the VIP. You need to deallocate the VM in order to update the backend API. Unfortunately you have to fully stop it.